# The 'Postman' icon is not displayed

Tags: icons, desktop, ubuntu-18.04

I have a strange [PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdlTO.png).
I installed Postman following the instructions from the Internet.
Now it can be opened, works fine etc. but icon is not displayed.
occupies a place, shows that it is open and it writes a name when it crosses over it but irritates me because it can not be seen. What is the problem and how can I fix it? I tried to reinstall it and same happened...

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again? Restarting ubuntu...

Comment: @Erubiel I tried and it's still same...

Comment: https://medium.com/@canoodle/adding-icon-launcher-for-postman-native-app-in-ubuntu-a48a3917c786